# How to change vector tile source provider in TangramJS

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, vector-tiles, mapzen, tangram

I rely on the Mapzen API to serve vector tiles to TangramJS which render in Leaflet using a style similar to Bubble Wrap (https://github.com/tangrams/bubble-wrap/blob/gh-pages/bubble-wrap-style.yaml).

Since the unfortunate announcement of Mapzen closing it's services in Feb 2018 I am looking to continue using TangramJS and hopefully just a difference tile source.

Do the other providers (Mapbox, OpenMapTiles, ThunderForest) suggested by Mapzen's blog post (https://medium.com/postzen/mapzen-alternatives-aa6d857e3532) just 'drop in' their own URL and things continue on exactly the same?

Below is the sources section from the Bubble Wrap style.

```
sources:
    mapzen:
        # EraserMaps the app only supports MVT format tiles
        type:  MVT #TopoJSON
        url:  https://tile.mapzen.com/mapzen/vector/v1/512/all/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt
        #url:  http://tile.dev.mapzen.com/mapzen/vector/v1/all/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt
        #url:  //localhost:8080/vector/all/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt
        # road labels in Tangram JS are broken when overzooming, set max_zoom: 18 to preview fix
        url_params:
            api_key: global.sdk_mapzen_api_key
        tile_size: 512
        max_zoom: 16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change your scene file, the other providers have a different schema to mapzen. I've started working to create a scene file for OpenMapTiles and it's quite different so far. Roads are under transportation, 'kind' is now class, and the values are different, and so on.

Comment: That is frustrating. So no services use the same schema? I would have thought it'd be some sort of open standard.

Comment: The other issue I've run into is that buffered tiles seem to make labelling behave in odd ways